# networkx maximum_flow crashes on some pairs of nodes

Tags: networkx, max-flow

I have a graph composed of 742 edges, and 360 nodes.
I want to compute max flow between some pairs of nodes and it happens, for some of them the `nx.maximum_flow` ends with the pasted error, despite the fact that a path exists between the two concerned nodes.
Any idea what causes that?
Thanks.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-6dae3501e3d0> in <module>()
      1 #print(nx.shortest_path(G,source="Sink_0",target="node_32"))
----> 2 nx.maximum_flow(G, "Sink_0", "Aircraft2_32")

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/flow/maxflow.pyc in maximum_flow(G, s, t, capacity, flow_func, **kwargs)
    156         raise nx.NetworkXError("flow_func has to be callable.")
    157 
--> 158     R = flow_func(G, s, t, capacity=capacity, value_only=False, **kwargs)
    159     flow_dict = build_flow_dict(G, R)
    160 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/flow/preflowpush.pyc in preflow_push(G, s, t, capacity, residual, global_relabel_freq, value_only)
    420     """
    421     R = preflow_push_impl(G, s, t, capacity, residual, global_relabel_freq,
--> 422                           value_only)
    423     R.graph['algorithm'] = 'preflow_push'
    424     return R

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/flow/preflowpush.pyc in preflow_push_impl(G, s, t, capacity, residual, global_relabel_freq, value_only)
    279                 break
    280             u = next(iter(level.active))
--> 281             height = discharge(u, False)
    282             if grt.is_reached():
    283                 # Global relabeling heuristic.

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/flow/preflowpush.pyc in discharge(u, is_phase1)
    156                 # We have run off the end of the adjacency list, and there can
    157                 # be no more admissible edges. Relabel the node to create one.
--> 158                 height = relabel(u)
    159                 if is_phase1 and height >= n - 1:
    160                     # Although the node is still active, with a height at least

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/flow/preflowpush.pyc in relabel(u)
    125         """
    126         grt.add_work(len(R_succ[u]))
--> 127         return min(R_node[v]['height'] for v, attr in R_succ[u].items()
    128                    if attr['flow'] < attr['capacity']) + 1
    129 

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you imported/created your graph correctly, then it's probably a bug that you should report on the networkx github page. Without knowing the exact structure of G, it is impossible to judge for anybody else what exactly is going on.

Comment: I'm not a graph expert at all but, does it make sense that a path may exist between two nodes without being able to calculate the maximum flow between them?
But your suggestion is right. I'm going to create an issue on their github.

Comment: If there is a path, there is a flow. Therefore there is a min flow. Maybe you are considering an undirected path as a path? @radar

Comment: It is a DiGraph. And maximum_flow_value returns a value.
Actually, I have this problem only with networkx 1.11 but not with 2.1. So maybe it was not worth posting.

Comment: Ok it should be a bug then, good luck (think about the "@" else people don't see replies).

Comment: Is there any way you can provide the graph?  Would also help if you added it to the bug report you (I assume it was you) filed on this.